# problem in enabling Commerce 2CheckOut module

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I have added [2CheckOut](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_2checkout) module to drupal 7, then go to drupal admin and modules page to enable it, the module tell me it needs  Commerce_paymen as required module "Requires: Commerce_payment (missing)".

So, how can I find this module "Commerce_payment" I searched it out but without luck.

this what i got in modules page:
Commerce 2CheckOut  7.x-1.x-dev Payment using 2checkout
Requires: Commerce_payment (missing), Rules (disabled), Entity tokens (enabled), Entity API (enabled)

Answer (score 1):

The `commerce_payment` module is bundled with [Drupal Commerce](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/). Please feel free to contact 2Checkout tech support at techsupport@2co.com for assistance with your integration.